# Any ideas on how to elegantly reuse old answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-question

Sometimes a valid question is asked that is a rehash of another question that was not properly handled, usually these questions have a many duplicate answers. I understand your not supposed to have duplicates in general. But sometimes the data of the answers is spread so thin that its hard to find the useful whole.

Im really talking about my totally bastardized answer on this question:
"[Correct anti-aliasing color when moving to a new background?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/correct-anti-aliasing-color-when-moving-to-a-new-background)". Which I am currently hating vehemently. Basically because it also contains self reference which is not feeling very good either.

So i was actually thinking:

- When is it okay to restart the discussion with the better full and complete answer, by combining many answers ideas and topics with references to originals (or not)?
- Is it okay to copy HUGE sections of valid explanation that really does the job but is slightly modified to fit the context?

Comment: If you're re-using an answer, then likely the question can be marked duplicate and you can refer to said answer in other question.

Comment: @DA01 but sometimes that would lead to long chains. The duplicates game is a bit silly also since in fact we do have many many near duplicate answers anyway. What im saying is sometimes the complete answer is several other answers with a twist.

Comment: I that case, I'd reference the other answers via links then write out the twist. But I'm lazy. :)

Comment: @DA01 yeah i can see that from your reputation score. Lazy indeed. :D